# jQuery dropdown menu, tab accessibility

Tags: jquery

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/emJcx/1/

I have a drop down menu that is a simple show and hide on hover. I would like this dropdown menu to be accessible by using the tab keys as well. Using this code:

```
$("li.trigger a").focus(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().find('ul').show();
});
```

I have enabled the dropdown to show on the head link focus.

The blur gets a little more complex. I tried this:

```
$("li.trigger ul li:last-child a").blur(function(){ 
    $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

But it only works with forward tabs, not back-tabs (shift-tabs).

I have also tried something like this:

```
$('li.trigger').has('a:focus').find('ul').toggle();
```

But naturally this does not work.

Any thoughts on how this could work.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use `addClass()` to do that? It doesn't seem like a completely optimal solution, but it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/emJcx/24/

It may not be the most optimal solution possible, but here is what I did:

1. You were limiting your `focus` event to the class of trigger but one of your `li` tags did not have that class so I removed it for now. You might want to button this down a bit because at the moment it will run for every li on the page.
2. I changed the code to hide all of the child `ul` tags prior to showing the one you are currently on. This way when you shift-tab back up to the parent menu items and move away from the parent of a given sub menu it will disappear.
3. I removed your `blur` event because it would have caused an issue when shift-tabbing back off of the last item. The functionality remains the same because the additional hide actually takes care of this.

The new code is simply:

```
$("li a").focus(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('ul').hide();
  $(this).parent().find('ul').show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks David, but this solution does not seem to work for shift-tab, it hides the dropdown menu

Comment: @superUntitled We may be using different browsers because it works how I would imagine it should - that is, it only hides the dropdown after after you shift back up to the main menu and change tabs. What browser are you using?

Comment: Hey, I am using Firefox 8.0.1. Your solution does work, except for when you shift-tab from the last link of a sub-menu

Comment: @superUntitled I saw that after testing in response to your first comment and have added a fix for you

Comment: @superUntitled Looks like you changed the code the same way I did